# How does one register an App with LinkedIn Developers?

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I cannot register an app with linkedin at https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps because for any input I make, I get redirected to an error page "We are getting things cleaned up." This happened last week as well as today.

Am I making incorrect inputs (although I wouldn't know what I could possibly add or change)?

Is there an alternative, working way to add an app?

Answer (score 0):

This link should work - https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer?newapp=

Click the create application button on this page